# Flash fadeIn / fadeOut

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

there is something similar for AC3 like fadeIn, fadeOut from jQuery?

Now I use `visible=false` but I want to animate this, from opacity 0 to opacity 1

Comment: tween the `alpha` value of the object you want to fadeIn or out.

Comment: can you give me more details, maybe some codes?

Comment: It's easier to do by hand that it is to learn to code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achiev this with the tween class,this would be a fadein

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;

var myTween = new Tween(mc, "alpha", Strong.easeIn, mc.alpha, 1, 3, true);
```

And here the "naked" one for all Properties:

```
var myTween:Tween = new Tween(object, "property", EasingType, begin, end, duration, useSeconds);
```

Reference [Here](http://help.adobe.com/de_DE/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/Tween.html)

Also not the the Standard tweening class is not the best to use. It has a lot of problems with simultanious tweens. Best to use Tweenlite/max which can be found here: http://greensock.com/tweenlite

Reagarding comment, its been a long since i done as3 and currently have no method of testing it but this should work or atleast give you enough to fuigure it out. Import point to remeber is that the object must be alpha=0 but NOT visible=false; :

```
myObject.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,overMouse);
myObject.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,outMouse);

function overMouse(e:MouseEvent):void {
 var myTweenIn = new Tween(myObject, "alpha", Strong.easeIn, myObject.alpha, 1, 3, true);
}
function outMouse(e:MouseEvent):void {
     var myTweenOut = new Tween(myObject, "alpha", Strong.easeIn, myObject.alpha, 0, 3, true);
    }
```

Comment: I want to fadeIn an element on hover, how can i do this?

Comment: @user1670082 Edited Post, Take a look

Comment: i know its stupid, but how i fadeOut after, i know to use mouse out but how i do the tween?

Comment: @user1670082 I have added the fadout as a pair to the fadein. Note the first number in the tween? Thats the FINAL Value. it starts with the current myObject.alpha and moves it to 1 on mouseover and 0 on mouse_out

Comment: and how can i put alpha 0 to my button from the start?

Comment: @user1670082 If you are using adope flash cs whatever simply select the  moviclip and find the alpha slider in the properties. alternativly you can use myObject.alpha = 0; in the frame where the button is first put onto the stage